# How to enlarge a button as it receives focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my button bigger when it receives focus:

```
<html>
    <form name="myForm">
      <button onfocus="width=200; height=200">myButton</button>
      <button>myOtherButton</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form name="myForm">
    <button onfocus="this.style.width = '200px'; this.style.height = '200px';">myButton</button>
    <button>myOtherButton</button>
</form>
```

I imagine after implementing this, you will also want to restore the size after the focus leaves.

```
<button onfocus="this.style.width = '200px'; this.style.height = '200px';" onblur="this.style.width = this.style.height = '';">myButton</button>
```

If you're doing much more than that, I would recommend separating this code into functions and making better JavaScript design decisions.