# How to make a Xul button bigger using css as it get focus?

Tags: javascript, css, xul

I saw at [this](http://www.mozilla.org/access/keyboard/snav/css_usage.html) page that I can use CSS to change my button as it get focused. But trying with the following code in the CSS didn't work:

```
button:focus {
    style.width='200px';
}
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: this is not css, valid css should looks like this `button:focus { width: 200px; }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720548/how-to-make-a-button-bigger-as-it-receive-focus

Comment: @epascarello talking about Xul and css now.. that answer is not appliable.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
button:hover { 
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: it's very difficult when there are no "compile error message".. :)